# How to show the amount of PayPal purchases on my website

Tags: javascript, php, api, paypal

I have a website where I'm trying to get to a 1500 purchases goal and display the progress on my website (shown in the image below).

[image]

I have PayPal buttons integrated on my website where I've applied the following code:

Javascript:

```
<script>
function clickCounter() {
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.clickcount) {
            localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
        } else {
            localStorage.clickcount = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "" + localStorage.clickcount + " <br>Subscribers So Far! And...<br>" + (1500 - +localStorage.clickcount) + "<br>Subscribers To Go" ;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
    }
}
clickCounter()
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" id="paypal-btn1" type="button">Click me!</button></p>
<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" id="paypal-btn2" type="button">Click me!</button></p>
<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" id="paypal-btn3" type="button">Click me!</button></p>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Which creates a counter for every time a any of the 'Buy Now' buttons are clicked. Problem is the counter is reset on different browsers and devices because there is no log in feature to maintain the counter memory.
I'm thinking of possibly integrating some sort of PayPal API command to fetch the results from my PayPal data but I can't seem to find the directions/information on how to do that. Does anyone know of if it's possible to use the PayPal API and how or if there is any changes I can make to the current code I have?

Comment: No experience with their API but have you checked the documentation, looks pretty nice at first sight. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using IPN to automatically update your own database when new donations are made.  Then you can pull the data for your chart from your own database.

Review the [PayPal IPN documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) to get familiar with it.  Then you can take a look at the [basic sample IPN script PayPal provides](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/tree/master/php).

If you want something a little more advanced you can use [this library](https://packagist.org/packages/mike182uk/paypal-ipn-listener) on Packagist and install with Composer.

IPN can be a little tricky to test and troubleshoot, so I would review this guide on [how to test PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/) as well.

Comment: That sounds great! Thank you. Do you have some code examples or somewhere with some code examples for me to see in order to understand more & hopefully implement?